# How can I import a package having the same namespace without collision in Scala?

Tags: scala

Say I have library classes in package `com.foo`, and that I've already published this library to a repository. I'd like to do some side-by-side testing with newer version of (as-yet unpublished) com.foo library and I don't want to mix up classes in old/new com.foo packages.

Can I import "old" com.foo alongside "new" com.foo to run comparison tests without all their classes getting intermingled and colliding?

Comment: The obvious answer is to use two classloaders for each of the two versions. But there is no mechanism at the language level, such as rename on import. At the build level, folks use version directories for the different sources.

Comment: This is probably something better solved by your build tool. What are you using for that?

Comment: If you don't want to get into classloader mess try to use a build tool like SBT. Have subprojects or separate projects naturally use separate classpaths to load your libraries. In this case you won't have both versions available at runtime, but you can save output somewhere else and then diff. This allows you to reuse the code that tests those libraries as long as their interfaces are the same.